# AddEventListener for dynamic elements + listen to childs

Tags: javascript

Is there a proper way of adding a event listener that also listens for dynamically added elements (this part is simple enough), but this dynamic element will also have children that I want to include in the listen event.

Below the fiddle that don't work + the jQuery solution that does work, but I'm looking for a native JS solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/JeroenSormani/onjdha6k/1/

I know of two possible solutions, but none of them seem elegant to me:
1) Manually add listeners when adding the new elements
2) On `document.body` click loop through all the `event.target` parents to see if it has a `.item` class, seems like overkill to me.

Any other better way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure what exactly is wrong with 2? That's the way you're listening to events fired on dynamically added elements... You are basically using `document.body.addEventListener` and checking if `event.target` matches your criteria... `jQuery` does exactly this under the hood, with `$(body).on('click', '.my-el', ()=>{})`

Comment: @Miloshio #2 doesn't work for newly added elements (without manually adding the event listener again)

Comment: Whole point of `event.target` and event bubbling is exactly to work for newly added elements. Please post your code.

Comment: @Miloshio JSFiddle is available at the main post :-)
PS. in my previous comment I was referring to my #2 example in my JSF, not the 2nd possible mentioned solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from a friend I managed to find a fitting solution for my case. I used `e.target.matches()` to determine if the clicked element is part of the item I wanted to have the click event on.

This works flawlessly on existing and newly added elements, but has s

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('.item, .item *')) {
        // Do stuff
    }
})
```

Should be noted that it can require some additional code for browser compatibility (`.matches()` isn't compatible with all browsers, but there are ways to achieve that)

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided much information about what specifically you are trying to accomplish, but if you want to listen for the appearance of dynamically added elements I have found success with MutationObserver:

```
// observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);

    // include your code for reacting to each mutation here

  });    
});

// target node
var target = document.getElementById('my-id');

// configuration
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// start observer
observer.observe(target, config);

// stop observer -- use this when you want to stop observing
// observer.disconnect();
```

Every time a change happens to a child of #my-id, the observer will fire off the function passed to mutations.forEach()

With the code above you should be able to examine the mutation objects logged in the console to see how you can use the data they provide to achieve your desired behavior.